# Form POST, not reading any value

Tags: php, html, forms, post, mysqli

im busy with this for hours to solve it but it is not working. My logic has to work but isn't, this is the last place i would ask my question and i'm doing it right now, hope anyone could help me out.
I try to check the $_POST values in the MySql database using MySqli and checking if the count is right. After that im checking if the password is the same as the one given.
I've used that way so i could determine if the user has given an invalid username or password and show them an error about it.
My knowledge at the moment is that the login script does not reads any value that comes within the $_POST.
I could use some great help.
Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<form action="inc/login.php" method="post">
<label for="gr_username">Gamertag </label>
<input type="text" id="gr_username" name="gr_username" class="panel panel-default" placeholder="GT" style="width:120px;height:25px;"/>
<br>
<label for="gr_password">Password </label>
<input type="password" id="gr_password" name="gr_password" class="panel panel-default" placeholder="Password" style="width:120px;height:25px;"/>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value=" LOGIN "/>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

include_once('../../inc/db.php'); 
$link = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname); 

$username   = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['gr_username']);
$password0  = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['gr_password']);
$password  = hash('whirlpool', $password0);

if(!$link) 
{ 
header('Location: ../login.php?err=Servers not available at the moment! Please try again later. [ERRCODE: L01]');
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM leaders WHERE username = '" . $username . "'";
$res = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if(!$res) 
{ 
header('Location: ../login.php?err=Servers not available at the moment! Please try again later. [ERRCODE: L03]');
}
else 
{ 
    $totalrows = mysqli_num_rows($res); 
    if ($totalrows > 0) {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) 
    { 
    if ($password == $row['password']) {
        $_SESSION['gamertag'] = $row['username']; 
        $_SESSION['socialclub'] = $row['socialclub']; 
        $_SESSION['leaderid'] = $row['id'];
        } else { 
        header('Location: ../login.php?err=Invalid Password! Try again.');
        }
    } 
    header('Location: ../index.php?grmsg=You are successfully logged into the Leader Panel!');
} else {
header('Location: ../login.php?err=Username not found! Try again.');
}
}
?>
```

Hope you could help me out.
Thanks in advance!

- A.

Comment: You're missing the first argument to `mysqli_real_escape_string`. The first argument must be `$link`, and you have to call it after calling `mysqli_connect()`.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for that, i've just added that manually, but even when i didn't had set any `mysqli_real_escape_string` it wouldn't work neither.

Comment: so what happens when you post the form? you need `session_start()` by the way

Comment: What do you see if you just do `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: @meda ofcourse `session_start()` thanks for reminding me, it says Username is Invalid, It checks the username as first, and value is empty when calling back into my "error message". :(

Answer (score 0):

Since you got `Invalid Password! Try again.` it means that the user was at least found.

This confirms that the query works but also mean:

**`hash('whirlpool', $password0) != $row['password']`**

This is where you need to investigate why the condition is not met.

To start if I were you I would do:

```
if ($password == $row['password']) {
    //works
} else { 
    //header('Location: .....');
    echo "Invalid Password! Try again";
    echo "password0 : ".$password0."<br>";
    echo "password  hashed : ".$password."<br>";
    echo "password from db : ".$row['password']."<br>";
}
```

---

- Since you used whirlpool , make sure your fields are long enough
- make sure you saved the hash to your db and not the plain password (dangerous)

otherwise you will have to hash the db value again `hash('whirlpool', $row['password']);` which defeat the whole purpose of hashing.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
  <?php
session_start();
include ('connect.php');
    $login_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login_id']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string(SHA1($_POST['password']));

//your hash function here...

    include('connect.php');

    $chk = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin where name = '$login_id' AND password = '$password';");
    $count =  mysql_num_rows($chk);

    if($count=='1')
    {

        $_SESSION['name'] = $login_id;

    //to loggoed on page
        header("location:admin.php?id=1");

        }
        else {
        echo "<script>
    alert('Invalid Login...');
    window.location.href='index.php';
    </script>";

        }

?>
```